# What is the name for the distribution shape of a histogram with this kind of curvature?

Tags: normal-distribution, histogram

I have a histogram of points with a dip in the center of the bell, seeming to create two bells, or two clusters. What is the name for this kind of shaped distribution? This curve should be normal but doesn't quite seem to be.

[image: histogram]

Comment: What's the data? Perhaps there's a confounding variable that could explain the bi-modality?

Comment: @naught101That does seem to be the case. I am investigating. The data is Ted Cruz pct vote win by county in the US primaries.

Comment: In that case it's probably worth mapping the data..

Comment: If the data are percentages of votes, then I don't see why they "should be normal". Different sociodemographics probably come with very different voting patterns. The overall result could have pretty much *any* shape.

Comment: <Various weak political jokes deleted.> A serious confounder here is that I imagine that you are mixing primaries with quite different # of candidates. It's unsurprising if the overall pattern is at least a little complicated.

Comment: @NickCox I agree. Hence why I am looking to name the shape.

Comment: Since this is voting data it cannot be normal in distribution.

Comment: @Repmat Why's that

Comment: @incodeveritas The normal distribution is unbounded -- some of its probability is always outside any bounded interval. So bounded variables cannot be actually normal. Secondly, it's discrete -- a finite mixture of discrete distributions (with rational mixing proportions) -- not continuous, so again, cannot be actually normal. It's possible for something to be very well approximated by a normal, but that's not the same thing as being normal.

Comment: That's an [elephant inside a snake distribution](http://theliterarylink.com/prince1.html), not to be confused with the hat inside a snake distribution.

Comment: @Glen_b What kind of distribution is political data then? (Just came back to this..)

Comment: "political data" might have almost any distribution depending on what variable you're measuring if you mean things like proportions of people with some political preference ("do you approve of candidate X?", like the ) perhaps across some set of locations (like your counties), I answered that already -- it's bounded and discrete; more specifically a finite mixture of discrete distributions (with rational mixing proportions). That's about all you can say. It *might* in some cases make sense to approximate it as a mixture of binomial distributions. That would be the first thing I'd try. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... however it won't actually *be* that, that's just a model.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It could be a [bimodal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution)

Or then it could just be the a run of the mill normal distribution as the dip in the middle doesn't appear to be that big.

[image: bimodal distribution]

*Image [Bimodal.png](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bimodal.png) by Maksim, from Wikimedia commons; licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en)*

Comment: How do we translate S.D. values into percentage and something like that results in bimodalty following a mapping of data.

Comment: @subash "Bimodal" simply means "has two modes" -- there's more than one bimodal distribution, so if I understand what you're saying there (it's somewhat unclear) then your question doesn't have a unique answer.

Comment: The image from your post appears to be [taken from wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bimodal.png), authored by user [Maksim](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Maksim) (it was used in the Wikipedia article "[multimodal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution)"). Both the conditions of the license and StackExchange's own standards require proper attribution when you use work like this. Please attribute the authorship or replace the plot. (You're free to use this one I just generated - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdFuk.png )

Comment: @Glen_b - thanks for the heads up. Does the current update confirm with the standards? I'm not sure if I should attribute the article or the file itself.

Comment: @plumbus Thanks. Maksim made the picture, he didn't write the article, so it's it's his work making the image that you recognize ((though the addition of a link to that wikipedia page is useful) The first link I gave is the thing you're using (the wikimedia commons image) and that page contains a [link to the license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) (actually the image's page seems to list two different licenses, you're presumably able to pick one). You didn't modify the image so the license requires only two things: give credit and link to the license. ...ctd

Comment: ctd.. so something directly under the image, like *Image Bimodal.png by Maksim, from Wikimedia commons; licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.* with two embedded links (one to the image page `https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bimodal.png` where it gives the name of the image and the second to the license `https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en` where the license is mentioned) should cover it. ... (NB your addition of a link to that multimodal wikipedia page is useful for a different reason; you might keep that reference as well)

Comment: @Glen_b - made the changes you recommended. How does it look?

Comment: It was fine, thanks. However, I embedded the all links; I'd like to be able to point other people here to see an example of a suitable approach and I think that one-liner is sufficient. Sorry if I was unclear; the suggestion of keeping the article link was just for your answer not the license - I embedded that as well.

Comment: @Glen_b - no worries. I agree - one liner looks much better

Answer (score 1):

A bimodal distribution.  You could also say it's an almost-normal curve with negative kurtosis.  (Kurtosis refers to the spikiness of a normal curve; a bell-shaped curve that is very tall and elongated in height would have positive kurtosis).  Your curve also appears to have a long right tail, so it is skewed to the right.